# Stop pushPayload from triggering automatic fetches

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm currently manually pushing some data upon initialization of my Ember app using `pushPayload`. I'm using JSONAPI as the adapter.

When I push it the data (which loads correctly) it contains relationship references to other records that are not yet loaded (or may never load depending on how the user interacts with the page).

If Ember sees something like

```
{ 
   id: 1,
   type: 'project',
   relationships: 
     jobs: {
       data: [
         { id: [some_id_not_yet_loaded], type: 'job' }, 
         { id: [another_id_not_yet_loaded], type: 'job' }, 
       ]
     },
}
```

It then is automatically querying `/jobs/filter[id]=1,2,..x`. It's both unnecessary/not performant to issue this request. I realize this is part of the Ember Data default behavior but I'd like to be able to override it such that the Ember store will still maintain the references to both `jobs` but only hydrate them when the corresponding `project` is loaded (or not).

Comment: Hi Maschwenk, the default behavior is intended not to load relationships until you request them via `project.get('jobs')`. Can you show some more of the ember code here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing back a data key, if you pass back a links key with the appropriate URL to retrieve the related record at, Ember Data will lazily load the values as needed.